# Maximum size of document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, limitations, size

Colleague and I were going through ShP limitations. When we realized we can't find anywhere maximum size of document library.
I don't ask for a number of documents, as that information can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493258%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ListLibrary).
**Documents** | **30,000,000 per library**
I am asking of maximum size as capacity of doc library.
Is it limited only by size of Site collection or there is some other size limitation?

Comment: Like you mention, Site collection limits and content database limits (and perhaps userlimits).

Comment: So as I predicted, by Microsoft recommendation 200GB limitation of content database and by it limitation of site collection, we can say limit for one document library is 200 GB?

Comment: Partially for the content database, as that's Microsoft's recommendation but there are a lot of circumstances such as versioning, maximum numbers of objects in a content database etc. And the list view threshold. Take a look at Microsoft's whitepapers regarding software limits and plan your setup. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493258(v=office.16).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think content database is your limit and if you want to use this library for archive, you don't have any limits at database size. Maybe only number of items.

[image]